# Rails Include Current User's Post in Timeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have rails project where user have timeline which include posts of users which he/she follows.
I made a code in Post model:

```
scope :of_followed_users, -> (following_users) { where user_id: following_users }
```

So I can show the Posts in PostController like this:

```
@posts = Post.where(user_id: @current_user.following)order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

But the problem is that I want users also could see his/her posts in timeline nevertheless. What is the best practice to do that? Do I have to follow myself first? I have tried using an array where `user_id: [@current_user.following, @current_user]` but it just shows the current_user's post. How am I able to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try this one `Post.where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ? ", @current_user.followingm@curretnt_user.id).order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)`

Comment: Thank you very much, but it doesn't work like that as I try it. It works with Post.where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ? ", @current_user.following.ids,@current_user.id).order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)

Comment: What you get in out put error or result ?

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: sub-select returns 16 columns - expected 1: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."followed_id" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = 22) OR user_id = 22 ) AND "posts".ORDER BY checkin_time DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?

Comment: try this let me know the output `Post.where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ? ", @current_user.following.ids,@curretnt_user.id).order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)`

Comment: Do you get correct data in `@current_user.following` ?

Comment: yes, I actually using your latest answer as my answer, as I explained above. It works if I add ids after @current_user.following

Comment: Does your issue resolved ?

Comment: yes, sir. the issue is resolved! thank you very much.

Comment: Can i post it as answer ? will you upvote and accept it ?

Comment: yes sir, i will upvote and i will accept it

Comment: I posted query as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query

```
Post.where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ? ", @current_user.following.ids,@curretnt_user.id).order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

Answer (score -1):

In another concept: 
Why you don't add an action to the posts which will make the owner of the post as a follower as well to the post.

Example: 
User(x) Added a Post(Y)
User(x) is a follower of Post(Y)

It happens when you are in 'create' action for the post, ask the model to handle the following concept.

PostController:

```
def create
 if @post.save 
  bla bla bla
 end
end
```

Post Model:

```
after_save :follow_post

private 
def follow_post
 do the follow action 
end
```

Comment: it's just not good for the user experience in my opinion. you don't have to follow yourself

Comment: Thanks, guys, it's just a tricky idea to solve it. 
Even if you noticed, Some famous platforms do this with different approaches.